# Не создаются объекты в MongoDB через rails-приложение

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

В index на старницу вывожу @all и все время получаю пустой массив. Если убрать .documents то получаю Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000003faefd0.
P.S. ощущение, что упускаю что-то очень простое, так как первый раз пытаюсь встать на рельсы

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
@all = Article.where(title: "заголовок новости").documents;
end

def create
Article.create(title: "заголовок новости", text: "текст новости")
redirect_to articles_path
end
```

Comment: А уверены, что записи действительно создаются? Если заменить `create` на `create!`, что происходит при создании? И если посмотреть в БД чем-нибудь сторонним, там есть данные?

Comment: Вроде бы решил проблему. Вместо Articles.where надо articles.find_by и тогда все на первый взгляд нормально.